# Quarkus Unit Test Mock The Serive classs

Tags: junit, quarkus

I am Using Junit5 with Quarkus F/w.
when I try to Mock Service class by Using @InjectMock(io.quarkus.test.junit.mockito.InjectMock) it gives an error
Like **org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.TestInstantiationException: Failed to create test instance**
and another side when I am using @InjectMocks which belongs to (org.mockito.InjectMocks) package
Junit Running fine but, the Service class Did not Mock it is hit a real DAO class and inserted data
inside database

total conclusion in @InjectMocks is not working.

Please give me any suggestion but this mocking
Thank you.

Comment: Please update the question with the code you are using

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.